# I want the searchbox to disappear from all pages except product page with React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> When i do this ternay operator the result is that the searchbox desappear from every page. The idea is only to show in /products. Thank you if you could help me with this, very much appreciated.

````
function Header() {
let location = useLocation();


{location === "/products" ? (
                      <li>
                        <form action="#" class="form-box f-right">
                          <input
                            type="text"
                            name="Search"
                            placeholder="Search products"
                          />
                          <div class="search-icon">
                            <i class="ti-search"></i>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </li>
                    ) : null}```
````

Comment: Print `location` and see what it actually is. Or check the documentation: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`location` is an object (try to console.log it).
You probably want `location.pathname`

```
  function Header() {
    let location = useLocation();
    console.log('this is the location obj: ', location);
    {
      location.pathname === '/products' ? (
        <li>
          <form action="#" class="form-box f-right">
            <input type="text" name="Search" placeholder="Search products" />
            <div class="search-icon">
              <i class="ti-search"></i>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
      ) : null;
    }
  }
```

for additional reference: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation

Comment: I've already did it and the path is correct. /products is correct.

Comment: `let location = useLocation();
  
  console.log("----------------------");
  console.log("helloo", location.pathname);
  console.log("----------------------");`

Comment: yes but in your question you compare `location === "/products"` you should compare the string `location.pathname === "/products"`